# ASP.NET Core 2.1 app not picking up appsettings.Development.json even though I specify ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONENT=Development explicitly. Why?

Tags: asp.net-core-2.1

So I am working on an ASP.NET Core 2.1 Web API. I specified two sets of configurations for "Development" and "Production" explicitly by the following two functions:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(option => option
        .UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))                                              
}

public void ConfigureDevelopmentServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(option => option
        .UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
}
```

In the appsettings.json, I have:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost; Database=datingApp; Uid=appuser; Pwd=zhanxucong"
    }
}
```

In the appsettings.Development.json, I have:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    },
    "ConnectionStrings": {
      "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=DatingApp.db"
    }
  }
}
```

When I learned through the tutorial, the instructor said that by convention, when ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development is set, ASP.NET Core will call the more specific configure function (i.e. ConfigureDevelopmentServices) and use the more specific appsettings config file (i.e. appsettings.Development.json). And I can confirm that it had worked fine on my Windows and Mac. However, when I run this app on Linux, after running ef migration with the above settings, I get the following errors:

```
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 2.1.4-rtm-31024 initialized 'DataContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite' with options: None
System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'server'.
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnectionStringBuilder.GetIndex(String keyword)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnectionStringBuilder.set_Item(String keyword, Object value)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.set_ConnectionString(String value)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Storage.Internal.SqliteRelationalConnection.CreateReadOnlyConnection()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Storage.Internal.SqliteDatabaseCreator.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Keyword not supported: 'server'.
```

Any idea why this error will happen? Is it related to Linux being case-sensitive? Thanks!

Update: My Program class and my StartUp class (default ctor provided by dotnet-cli tool by running "dotnet new webapi":

Program class:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

StartUp class:

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    // ConfigureServices, ConfigureDevelopmentServices, Configure methods.
}
```

Comment: Hi Xucong, just for funsies, put this in one of your views and run the app on windows and linux and see if there is any difference `<p> ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = @hostingEnv.EnvironmentName</p>`  Linux is indeed case sensitive and would cause an issue if you do not have matching case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers provided. I really appreciate it and I learned a lot.

As for my bug, it is actually due to a very stupid mistake:

In my appsettings.Development.json file, the `"ConnectionStrings"` is nested within `"Logging"`. Therefore, when the `ConfigureDevelopmentServices` method is invoked, it will not be able to find `ConnectionStrings` in the appsettings.Development.json file and will fall back to configurations specified in appsettings.json, which is configured for connecting to a MySQL database. Hence the errors shown in my problem statement.

This observation is inspired by [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/8277).

Answer (score 1):

Keep three nested files like `appsettings.json`, `appsettings.Development.json` and `appsettings.Production.json`. Then environment name from env. Mention which file to use at Startup.cs and in bash set environment using,

```
$ export ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
```

Take the appropriate file depending on the environment. Replace the startup constructor with this.

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // code removed...
}
```

Please be consistent while writing environment variable names.
Linux environment variable names are case-sensitive.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I am thinking about making the configuration more explicit as well. But I still do not understand why on Linux it behaves differently than on Windows or Mac.

Comment: Also, I noticed that your StartUp class is setup a bit differently than mine. Are you using ASP.NET Core 2.0? Cos I believe they made some changes about the StartUp class and Program class in 2.1. I have updated my defaults from 2.1 in case you want to have a look. Thanks.

Comment: i am not aware of the changes between 2.0 and 2.1

Comment: The part i mentioned is same.

Comment: @Xucong Please change the startup constructor and export environment variable name while running in linux

Comment: Thanks, I would give it a try.